# how to turn On/off Activity Recognition in google Api Client Programmatically

Tags: android, google-fit

I am working on a health app using google fit In which i have a setting option to turn On/Off Activity detection . I researched a lot but didn't get any solution for it . Can anyone tell me how to achieve this funtionality?

Comment: Have a look at this example https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/ActivityRecognition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop activity recognition you have to do this :

```
ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.removeActivityUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                getActivityDetectionPendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this);
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi) is the documentation if you wanna have a look

Comment: Does this turn off the detection or it will remove all previous detected data. And how to turn it on again.

Comment: It will remove all activity updates for the specified PendingIntent. I would recommend saving the previous data .

Comment: Ok .  Got it .. Actually I am using Fitness.HistoryApi to read all dataTypes I am not using ActivityRecognition . Should i turn it on First time from my application or it by default in enable mode .If yyou see google fit  app so you can see the activity detection option in settings of it .. That the same thing  i want to achieve ..